# Rotate animation not working on span ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

**The animation works but it only fades it. No rotation like it is supposed to. I tried it on a div id and it worked.**

**Is my span code correct? or any errors?**

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><span id="jrm-featured-products" style="font-family: Poiret One; font-size: 36px;">Featured  Products</span></p>
```

And here is my CSS :-

```
 @-webkit-keyframes rotateInDownLeft {
    0% {
       -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
        transform-origin: left bottom;
       -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
         transform-origin: left bottom;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
         transform: rotate(0);
         opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    @keyframes rotateInDownLeft {
    0% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
         -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
         -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
          transform-origin: left bottom;
         -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
         -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
         -ms-transform: rotate(0);
          transform: rotate(0);
         -moz-transform: rotate(0);
          opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    #jrm-featured-products.animate {
         -webkit-animation: rotateInDownLeft 3s;
         -moz-animation: rotateInDownLeft 3s;
          animation-name: rotateInDownLeft;
         visibility: visible;
    }

    #jrm-featured-products {
         visibility:  hidden;
    }
```

**The animation works but it only fades it. No rotation like it is supposed to. I tried it on a div id and it worked.**

**Is my span code correct? or any errors?**

P.S. I'm using the jquery plugin Waypoints so that is why there is a .animate. (it toggles it hence creating the animation when the elemet comes into view) but that isn't too relevant to my problem.

Also, i'll spare you the long story, but I really need it to target the span id rather than the div id.

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the span to `display: block`.

`<span>` elements are, by default, set to `display: inline`, while `<div>` elements are, by default, set to `display: block`. Only [block level elements can be transformed](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transformable-element). Though a span isn't a block level element, you can make it behave as one by settings its display property to `block`.

Read more about inline vs block level elements here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/

Comment: Thanks this worked, but it took the width of the div that it was in, rather than staying the size it was. So it still ended up messing up my positioning. Errr! don't think there is a work around though. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

set span display to ' block ', in default span is an inline element

Answer (score 0):

Div takes the whole row as its width,but span width area is only the area covered by the text or the image,so it is not getting place to rotate,give some width to span by style="width:500px"

because span is INLINE and div is BLOCK

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display: inline-block`

The span's width will shrink to fit with the content